# How is this site increasing the internet's signal-to-noise ratio?

Tags: discussion

Although this site gets some interesting challenge questions. But I don't get, as in how is this site increasing the internet's signal-to-noise ratio?

How do you think it would be beneficial to future visitors?

How and why would a random internet searcher land on this site?

Comment: How and why did **you** land on this site?

Comment: @Quincunx Through *Hot Network Questions*.

Comment: I found this site through Area 51. It seems like some of the things here are useful; a [Google search for "compress chess board"](https://www.google.com/search?q=compress+chess+board) shows this site as the second result.